# scroll at the left when first open excel-macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro and it perfectly run. however, the result is always shown at the right (latest column).
[image: pic]

I tried to add the macro:

```
select.range("A1")
```

or

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

and it still is not working.

Is there anyone know how to make the scroll bar at the left (column A) when first open?

Comment: Why don't you add the code (*I have a macro... etc*) to the question ?

Comment: You can use `Range("A1").Select` to goto the first cell. `Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"` will also work.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue.
I add this line "ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-1"

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `Scroll:=True` from your code, to scroll the worksheet to the activated range.

Try this:

```
Application.Goto Reference:=Sheet1.Range("A1"), Scroll:=True
```